# How can I use the Java Access Bridge with Java 6?

Tags: java, c++, java-access-bridge

I want to use the Java Access Bridge with an application that uses an older version of the Java Runtime Environment. (Java 6)

JAB works fine for with the "public" JRE (SE 7). But the target application has its own JRE (SE 6). Neither Java Monkey nor Java Ferret display any information about the application.

I know that it is possible to get information from Java 6 applications, as there are third party applications that make use of JAB to get access to it. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

**To use the Java Access Bridge with Java 6 or below, [you will need to manually install Java Access Bridge 2.0.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/setup.htm#jab-installing-java-access-bridge).**

The Java Access Bridge wasn't included with Java by default until Java 7. Any earlier version of Java will require a manual installation. (Refer to [Oracle's installation guide for JAB 2.0.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/setup.htm#downloading-jab))

> Java Access Bridge is integrated into Java SE 7 Update 6 and later.
>   Consequently, you only require Java Access Bridge 2.0.2 for Java SE 6
>   and earlier.
>   <sub>[Oracle: Java SE Desktop Accessibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-136191.html)</sub>

See: [*Oracle - Installing Java Access Bridge*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/setup.htm#jab-installing-java-access-bridge)